# How to call javascript function from vbscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

how to call javascript function from vbscript.
i wrote like this

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
jsfunction()
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function jsfunction()
{
  alert("Hello")
}
</script>
```

but it is showing that type mis match how to achieve it. please help me.

Thank you,
Mihir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this  ...

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script language="JavaScript" >
function jsfunction()
{
  alert("Hello")
}

</script>
<%
Response.Write "Calling =" jsfunction() "."
%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: @road.. thank you but can you explain Response.Write "Calling =" jsfunction() "."  why you wrote like this... please

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you want this client side as opposed to ASP;

If you place the JScript block *before* the VBScript block (or wire the call to a load event) that will work fine. (IE only of course)

```
...
<head>

<script type="text/vbscript">
     function foo
         call jsfunction()
     end function
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     function jsfunction()
     {
       alert("hello");
     }
</script>

</head>

<body onload="foo()">
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling a VBScript function from Javascript
Your VBScript:

```
Function myVBFunction()
  ' here comes your vbscript code
End Function
```

Your Javascript:

```
function myJavascriptFunction(){
  myVBFunction();           // calls the vbs function
}
window.onload = myJavascriptFunction;
Alternatives (incompatible in some IE versions):


  // This one:
window.onload = function(){ myVBFunction(); }
  // This will also work:
window.onload = myVBFunction();
  // Or simply:
myVBFunction(); 
  // From a hardcoded link, don't write a semicolon a the end:
<a href="#" onclick="VBscript:myVBFunction('parameter')">link</a>
```

---

Inversed:
Calling a Javascript function from VBScript

```
Function myVBFunction()
  myJavascriptFunction()  
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of alert we should write return which is in turn print the values on page using response.write-

code is below -

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<script language="JavaScript" runat="server">
function test() {
return "Test";
}
</script>
<%
Response.Write "Value returned =" & test() & "."
%>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```